# How to build react apps using Ant build?

Tags: java, reactjs, npm, servlets, ant

I have a old Java Servlet project, I want to add react in that app. Currently, if I copy the build js files from react to Ant project and run them, they are working fine. But I want to automate the js build and copying them to specific path using my Ant build.

We can do it using maven build but I need Ant build supported.